# Does imperative emphatic sentence work?

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests, imperatives, do

I am from Singapore. I have heard many Singaporeans use imperative sentences with emphatic 'do' when they make requests or ask for something to be done a certain way. For example, they would say something like:

-Do get back to me once you have seen my email.

-Do take a seat and we will get back to you as soon as we can.

So do these sentences make sense? I have never seen other English speakers do this.

Comment: It's a bit effusive but quite commonplace. Do let us know if you can make the party.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing unusual in prefixing an invitation to do something with 'Do...' (at least to me as a British English speaker). It makes the tone seem warmer and more sincere.

**Do** sit down = I want you to be comfortable.

**Do** get back to me = Don't feel shy about pursuing the matter.

Comment: Agree. I've always taken such sentences as having a silent 'please' in front of it.

Comment: That makes sense. Because Singaporean English is based on British English. Thank you!

Comment: It can also be used for emphasis to make it stronger, not weaker. "**Do** get back to me" = "**Make sure you** get back to me".

Answer (score 0):

Usually people avoid the usage of DO before sentences, though it is gramatticaly correct. It is no harm by using DO in your conversation. I have given few examples below with and without DO in it.

**Do you want to leave? / You want to Leave?**
**Please do take rest. / Please take rest.**

Some sentences can not avoid using DO most of the times, such as the one below:

**Do you know me?**

Hope this helps!

Comment: "Do you want to leave?" is standard English usage, just the same as "Do you know me?". "You want to leave?" sounds very informal.

Comment: yup, but makes sense though it is informal. isn't it?

Comment: It makes sense, but sounds very abrupt unless you are speaking to someone you know very well.